# Polymorphism Play Framework 2 bindFromRequest

Tags: java, playframework-2.0

**EDIT**: The answer from the Play Framework developers is:

> It's not possible to do polymorphic binding with the Java form API, which is based on Spring databind. Spring databind to my knowledge doesn't support it.

A workaround to support Polymorphism is using ajax and JSON (Jackson will take care of the serlialization):

- In the view: The ajax data will be the JSON representation of the form.
- In the controller: Fetch the JSON:

  ```
  Animals animals=Json.fromJson(ctx.request().body().asJson(), Animals.class);
  ```

**END EDIT**

I have models like follow:

```
enum Type{ PARROT, ZEBRA} 

@JsonTypeInfo( use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,  include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,  
property = "animalType", visible = true)  
@JsonSubTypes({  
@Type(value = Mammal.class, name = "ZEBRA"),  
@Type(value = Bird.class, name = "PARROT"),
class Animal{
    public Integer color;
    public Type animalType;
}
class Bird extends Animal{
    public Integer airSpeed;
    public Integer wingType;
}
class Mammal extends Animal{
    public Integer legs;
}
class Animals{
    List<Animal> animals;
    Integer num;
}
```

And I POST in a controller the model **Animals**. Now I want to fetch the instance of Animals, as follows:

```
Animals animalsTest= Form.form(Animals.class).bindFromRequest().get();
```

If I fetch the content in **animalsTest.animals**, it will only contain a List of Animal objects. Nothing about their subtypes. There is a way to serialize/unmarshall a polymorphic entity in Play Framework 2?

Comment: This doesn't seem specific to Play. Say you got an instance of Animals (forget about Play). How would you know if each instance contained in the list is actually an instance of a subclass? You can't.

Comment: **@Janus Troelsen** The issue here is related with unmarshalling/serialization. Polymorphism can be serialized in several ways: Jackson may use **@JsonTypeInfo** for mapping, JAXB may use **@XmlSeeAlso** or directly the class name.
So I was asking If Play provide any annotation or anything I can use for set the mapping when serialization occurs.

Comment: **@Janus Troelsen** And in this case I could, since I have my enum:

    for(Animal animal: animals.list){
        if (animal.animalType== Type.PARROT){
            Mammal mammal=(Mammal)animal;
        }
    }